# Ideas of data structures in C for using on a Uno Card game?

Tags: c, data-structures, game-engine

So, I'm making an [Uno card game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_%28card_game%29) and I have to use 5 different types of data structure in C. I'm already using 4 (stack, linked list, double linked list and hash table).

Stack for the amount of cards, linked list for the cards on the hand of the users, double linked list circular (circular queue) for the sequency of moves and hash for a ranking with name and score.

Any idea of function for Uno card game that I could use a data structure?

Comment: A mutex to guard the deck?

Comment: I guess one data structure would have to be the data structure representing the cards, no? A struct containing the card number/type and the card color where applicable.

Comment: Take a look at **[UNO written in C#](http://unocsharp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/unocsharp/Uno/)**.